# change the type of my objectArray after saving in sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android

I have 2 simple different classes that one extends another. my first class is:

```
public class MyObject {}
```

without something in it.

and another:

```
public class People extends MyObject{
public  String UserId;

public void setUserId(String userId) {
UserId = userId;
}

public String getUserId() {
return UserId;
}
}
```

I am simply able to cast MyObject to People from an arraylist of "MyObject"s like this:

```
final People people = (People) myarray.get(position);
    //myarray is:ArrayList<MyObject> myarray
```

but somewhere I must save this array(I mean myarray) to sharedpreferences and then I read it somewhere else.so I save and read it by these methods:

```
  public static void SavePreferencesMyObjectArraylist(Context context, String key, ArrayList<MyObject> arrayList) {

    SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>() {}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(arrayList,type);
    editor.putString(key, json);
    editor.apply();

}

public static ArrayList<MyObject> LoadPrefrencesMyObjectArraylist(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>() {}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String gsonString = shared.getString(key, "");
    ArrayList<MyObject> arrayList = gson.fromJson(gsonString, type);

    return arrayList;

}
```

but the problem is when I read this array from sharedpreferences I cant cast the members of it to people! but why?!
meanwhile I'm pretty sure my sharedpreferences works fine.
please help me...

Answer (score 0):

try it out like this

//Store your object

```
public void setList(List<String> list){
    String list_s = new Gson().toJson(list);
    editor.putString("key_Value", list_s);
    editor.commit();
}
```

//get your object

```
public String[] getListDetails(){
    String stored_list = sharedPreferences.getString("key_value","");
    return new Gson().fromJson(stored_list, String[].class);
}
```

Comment: as you mentioned, I used MyObject instead of String in your method.and after getting the array from sharedpreferences as MyObject[], I still can't cast the member of this array to People! I get this error: MyObject cannot be cast to People